# How to prevent hard reset through recovery?

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset, privacy

Scenario is this , let's say someone stole my phone in public place I have installed anti-theft app and also pattern lock which is complex one. So he don't have access to my information. However he disconnected the phone from Internet so now I can't use anti-theft services on him. And then he boot into recovery of mine and did reset / cleared emmc , so my phone will be in state like how I got it as new! Thief got new phone!!! So is there anyway to prevent hard reset through recovery?

Comment: Most likely, a locked bootloader plus [Factory Reset Protection (FRP)](http://www.androidcentral.com/factory-reset-protection-what-you-need-know).

Comment: @Andy Yan I read the article you provided but I think it says about the inbuilt option of factory reset in settings not recoveries option of factory reset.